# Not able to start Kafka-Connect

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm getting the following error while starting the kafka-connect with the command "./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties". Therefore kafka-connect is not able to start properly.

```
[2017-11-02 18:03:12,852] DEBUG could not scan file org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/gen_rules_russian.txt in url file:/apps/confluent/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/commons-codec-1.9.jar with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner (org.reflections.Reflections:257)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class object from file org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/gen_rules_russian.txt
at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:32)
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:253)
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:202)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:123)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:221)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:68)
Caused by: org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class file from gen_rules_russian.txt
        at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:102)
        at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:24)
        at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:30)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: bad magic number: 2f2a0a20
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:825)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:154)
        at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:100)
        ... 11 more
```

Below is the content of the connect-standalone.properties file:

```
bootstrap.servers=dc2vmtkafmq01:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=1000
rest.host.name=dc2vmtkafmq01
rest.port=8083
plugin.path=/apps/confluent/confluent-3.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch
```

Below is the content of the quickstart-elasticsearch.properties file:

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=2
topics=compositionlog
topic.index.map=compositionlog:compositionlog
connection.url=http://10.104.185.143:9200
type.name=traceentity
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
```

Any idea about what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like issue with Java version - please make sure that you use correct one - Java 8.

Detailed spec is in [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#java).